# Add date column every loop

Tags: r, date

I want to prepare analysis data frames which i get from a website with rvest :

```
x <- list()
for (i in 18:19){
  for (j in 1:12) {
    x[[paste0("20",i,".",j)]]<-paste0("https://bkm.com.tr/secilen-aya-ait-sektorel-gelisim/?filter_year=20",i,"&filter_month=",j,"&List=Listele")
  }
}
```

Just create my links for two years for reading html with rvest and i want to bind in a single data frame

```
DF <- data.frame()

for (i in x){
  html_monthly <- read_html(i)
  temp_df <- html_table(html_monthly,fill=T)[[4]]
  temp_df <- temp_df[-c(1,2,28,29),]
  DF <- bind_rows(DF,temp_df)
}
```

This is what i get for a month

```
           X1     X2      X3    X4
1   A   292.290 57.920  158,36  12,48
2   B   2.725.497   540.511 1.920,41    100,50
3   C   25.260.026  8.000.259   4.641,49    567,45
4   D   2.582.916   527 667,90  0,19
5   E   24.041.009  12.196.630  3.483,63    477,84
6   F   973.180 24.216  719,08  5,66
7   G   5.368.531   2.203.468   1.444,43    153,74
```

I want to add date column in this data frame every loop according link.For example every month has 25 row and its date 2018-1 and main data frame DF in first 25 row will be 2018-1 and goes on

I've tried add a counter in loop and it was binding every temp_df a column from names(x)[counter], it works for 6 month but after that getting error

Any advice?

Comment: Iteratively adding to a `data.frame` scales very poorly: it might work well for the first few iterations, but each time you add rows to `DF`, it makes a complete copy of all of the data, which wastes time and memory. Better to keep them in a list (uncombined) and, at the end, use `do.call(rbind, list_of_frames)` (or `dplyr::bind_rows` or `data.table::rbindlist`).

Comment: `2018-1` is not a date as far as R is concerned. A date would be `2018-01-01`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: If this question is about adding columns to a frame, do you need to have any of the `rvest` code? It is generally better to have a minimal working example and filter out unnecessary code.

Comment: @r2evans Using rvest for html_table . I don't have problem with date formats i can convert it after that. In website which i get data is every month data frames is seperate links and has no date column.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty understanding your request. It seems you want to "harvest" information from some websites. This information has rownames and is limited to columns X1:X4. What you could do is save a collum with the date (Sys.Date()) and another with the website identification in each loop iteration. Afterwars you cna "tidy" your data (this is something you should look into)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```r
for (i in seq_along(x)){
  html_monthly <- read_html(x[[i]])
  temp_df <- html_table(html_monthly,fill=T)[[4]]
  temp_df <- temp_df[-c(1,2,28,29),]
  temp_df$date <- names(x)[i]
  DF <- bind_rows(DF,temp_df)
}
```

---

I suggest an alternative implementation, however.

```r
eg <- expand.grid(i=2018:2019, j=1:3)
eg
#      i j
# 1 2018 1
# 2 2019 1
# 3 2018 2
# 4 2019 2
# 5 2018 3
# 6 2019 3
```

The `expand.grid` function gives us every combination of the variables provided. I shorted to `j=1:3` just for demonstration, expand to what you want. From here, generating the URLs can be done more succinctly in one command. (While I used `sprintf` here, it can just as easily be done with `paste`/`paste0` with the same columns/vectors.) I name them in a format that will make `as.Date` easier later.

```r
urls <- sprintf("https://bkm.com.tr/secilen-aya-ait-sektorel-gelisim/?filter_year=%d&filter_month=%d&List=Listele", eg$i, eg$j)
names(urls) <- sprintf("%d-%02d-01", eg$i, eg$j)
urls
#                                                                                          2018-01-01 
# "https://bkm.com.tr/secilen-aya-ait-sektorel-gelisim/?filter_year=2018&filter_month=1&List=Listele" 
#                                                                                          2019-01-01 
# "https://bkm.com.tr/secilen-aya-ait-sektorel-gelisim/?filter_year=2019&filter_month=1&List=Listele" 
#                                                                                          2018-02-01 
# "https://bkm.com.tr/secilen-aya-ait-sektorel-gelisim/?filter_year=2018&filter_month=2&List=Listele" 
#                                                                                          2019-02-01 
# "https://bkm.com.tr/secilen-aya-ait-sektorel-gelisim/?filter_year=2019&filter_month=2&List=Listele" 
#                                                                                          2018-03-01 
# "https://bkm.com.tr/secilen-aya-ait-sektorel-gelisim/?filter_year=2018&filter_month=3&List=Listele" 
#                                                                                          2019-03-01 
# "https://bkm.com.tr/secilen-aya-ait-sektorel-gelisim/?filter_year=2019&filter_month=3&List=Listele"
```

From here, I find it's generally better to grab the data up front into a list, and then do whatever modifications in a later step. (It is certainly fine to add the column within this `lapply`, but that's mostly preference.)

```r
library(rvest)
lst_of_frames <- lapply(urls, function(url) html_table(read_html(url), fill = TRUE)[[4]])
str(lst_of_frames[1:2])
# List of 2
#  $ 2018-01-01:'data.frame':   29 obs. of  5 variables:
#   ..$ X1: chr [1:29] "Isyeri Grubu" "Isyeri Grubu" "ARABA KIRALAMA" "ARAÇ KIRALAMA-SATIS/SERVIS/YEDEK PARÇA" ...
#   ..$ X2: chr [1:29] "Islem Adedi" "Islem Adedi(Kredi Karti)" "292.290" "2.725.497" ...
#   ..$ X3: chr [1:29] "Islem Adedi" "Islem Adedi (Banka Karti)" "57.920" "540.511" ...
#   ..$ X4: chr [1:29] "Islem Tutari (Milyon TL)" "Islem Tutari \n                (Kredi Karti)" "158,36" "1.920,41" ...
#   ..$ X5: chr [1:29] "Islem Tutari (Milyon TL)" "Islem Tutari \n                    (Banka Karti)" "12,48" "100,50" ...
#  $ 2019-01-01:'data.frame':   29 obs. of  5 variables:
#   ..$ X1: chr [1:29] "Isyeri Grubu" "Isyeri Grubu" "ARABA KIRALAMA" "ARAÇ KIRALAMA-SATIS/SERVIS/YEDEK PARÇA" ...
#   ..$ X2: chr [1:29] "Islem Adedi" "Islem Adedi(Kredi Karti)" "256.372" "2.967.019" ...
#   ..$ X3: chr [1:29] "Islem Adedi" "Islem Adedi (Banka Karti)" "49.296" "642.136" ...
#   ..$ X4: chr [1:29] "Islem Tutari (Milyon TL)" "Islem Tutari \n                (Kredi Karti)" "195,13" "2.185,84" ...
#   ..$ X5: chr [1:29] "Islem Tutari (Milyon TL)" "Islem Tutari \n                    (Banka Karti)" "14,77" "127,16" ...
```

And now for what I think is your original question, how to create this `date` column for each scraped frame.

```r
lst2_of_frames <- Map(function(nm, x) transform(x, date = as.Date(nm)), names(lst_of_frames), lst_of_frames)
results <- do.call(rbind, lst2_of_frames)

head(results, n=3)
#                          X1                       X2                        X3                                           X4
# 2018-01-01.1   Isyeri Grubu              Islem Adedi               Islem Adedi                     Islem Tutari (Milyon TL)
# 2018-01-01.2   Isyeri Grubu Islem Adedi(Kredi Karti) Islem Adedi (Banka Karti) Islem Tutari \n                (Kredi Karti)
# 2018-01-01.3 ARABA KIRALAMA                  292.290                    57.920                                       158,36
#                                                            X5       date
# 2018-01-01.1                         Islem Tutari (Milyon TL) 2018-01-01
# 2018-01-01.2 Islem Tutari \n                    (Banka Karti) 2018-01-01
# 2018-01-01.3                                            12,48 2018-01-01

tail(results, n=3)
#                   X1          X2          X3        X4        X5       date
# 2019-03-01.27  YEMEK  45.639.403  39.193.997  2.629,09  1.219,64 2019-03-01
# 2019-03-01.28  DIGER   5.249.866  20.716.466  1.585,72    838,78 2019-03-01
# 2019-03-01.29 TOPLAM 350.282.800 185.000.312 68.957,28 11.658,47 2019-03-01
```

Comment: And additional question in line lapply , how can i remove 1 2 28 29 rows in every frame?

Comment: by adding `[-c(1,2,28,29),]` immediately after `[[4]]`? I have found that hard-coding row-numbers like that will fail when something on the remote end changes (without notifying you), so I suggest using something a little more deterministic, such as basing the row-removal on something in the data itself, not arbitrary row numbers.